# How to access to a specifc route of an angular application with nginx

Tags: angular, nginx

Good morning

I'm trying to access with nginx directly on one page of my angular application with a parameter in my route. This application is not in the root directory but in a subdirectory myapp      `http://my_serveur:my_port:/myapp/mypage/myparameter.`

I found a lot of solutions to access to a specific route of my angular application when it at the root of the nginx html directory.

```
 location / {
        try_files /$uri /$uri/ /roleapp/index.html;
  }
```

But I can't do it when the application is in subdirectory `/usr/share/nginx/html/myapp/`

I've changed the base href

> ng build --base-href=/myapp/

but nginx redirect the application to the index.html of the root directory.

I tried

```
location /myapp/ {
     #   alias /usr/share/nginx/html/roleapp/
        try_files /myapp/$uri /myapp/$uri/ /myapp/index.html;
     }
```

But Nginx send me back error 500.

Can you help me please?

Goofy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$uri` variable already includes the leading `/`, so your first `try_files` statement should actually look like this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /roleapp/index.html;
```

In the second case, the value of `$uri` already includes the `/myapp/` prefix, because the `location /myapp/ { ... }` block is only entered if `$uri` begins with `/myapp/`. So your second `try_files` statement should look like this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /myapp/index.html;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: thanks richard above solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know exactly what the problem is. This problem occurs in SPA (Single Page Applications). The url you type looks for the page directory/file wise. If you go to lets say mywebsiteurl/services it will look for file radar-input. In SPA's there's only one file and thats index.html so it won't find the services file and throw a 404.

SPA's have all their logic, routing in the index.html and once it gets served it handles everything for you (not case for non-spas), so if you go to mywebsiteurl/ it will just work fine and all urls will be loaded through app routing reason being that mywebsiteurl/ will look for index.html file and find it and serve that. So if your website is working fine by visiting the base url means that your static files are in the correct directory you just need to add this to you nginx.conf

```
location / {
try_files  $uri /index.html;        #check if uri exists else serve index.html as rewrite
}
```

which basically tries to first find the file in url , if it doesn't exist it will serve the index.html.